# zfs is mounted after mongod starts: how do I set the boot order?

Tags: zfs, systemd, boot

Fairly simple problem, I think, but I can't seem to get my head around a fix.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 and mounting zfs volumes with mongo-data at boot correctly with the config below in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants.

```
[Unit]
Description=ZFS startup target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Problem is that this happens after the mongod service is started, making mongod fail.

```
[Unit]
Description=MongoDB Database Server
Documentation=https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
# file size
LimitFSIZE=infinity
# cpu time
LimitCPU=infinity
# virtual memory size
LimitAS=infinity
# open files
LimitNOFILE=64000
# processes/threads
LimitNPROC=64000
# locked memory
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
# total threads (user+kernel)
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false
Restart=always
# Recommended limits for for mongod as specified in
# http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I read up about the `WantedBy`, `Requires` and `After` directives, but I'm not confident I understand them well enough to play around with them.

Comment: Where did you get this systemd unit?

Comment: Both came standard with the zfs and mongod packages

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with another service, which wanted to start before its files, which are on a ZFS dataset, became available.

I solved it with a very simple systemd override. You can do the same:

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/zfs.conf 
[Unit]
Requires=zfs.target
After=zfs.target
```

After a `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` (or of course a reboot) this will take effect. Enjoy!

Remember not to edit the systemd unit shipped with the package, as your changes would not be preserved when you update the package. Use override files (e.g. as above) instead.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I need. The systemd unit for mongo is in 

/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

though, which is a symlink to the one shipped with the package.

So not sure where to add the requires and after directives

Comment: You put it exactly where I showed in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure about adding the extra directory!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RequiresMountsFor; see

```
man systemd.directives
```

Option will be like
RequiresMountsFor=[mountpoint]
for example

```
RequiresMountsFor=/zfsmount
```

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try